# Is there a way to integrate LIST(of String) with SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

In the past, when we need to exclude members that fall into a certain category, we have used generic.list controls to do so as the example below shows:

First we do a query to list ALL eligible users who meet certain criteria.

```
sql="select ... from ourTable where certain conditions are true'
```

Then, we list certain groups in the list below and anyone user whose group is in that list will be excluded from participating.

```
        Dim listOfGroups = New List(Of String)(
         { _
              "ML02A", "ML02B", "ML03", "ML04", "ML05", "ML06", "ML07A", "ML07B", "AP05", _
             "AP06", "AP07A", "AP07B", "AP09A", "AP10", "AP12A" _
        })

        If Not listOfGroups .Contains(txtPre.Text) Then
            lblNA.Text = "Members in group<b>" & txtPre.Text & "</b> are not eligible to participate in this event."
        End If
```

This has always worked beautifully for us.

This time around, the list is well over 200,000; too many to manually include in the list below.

Is it possible to integrate list with SQL Server database?

Or perhaps, is there a way to handle this using stored proc and emitting the same exclusionary message via our asp.net app?

Our app is written in vb.net but I would be more than happy for any c# solutions that I can convert to vb.net

Can generic.list control be used like wildcard in sql server?

For instance, in SQL Server, we could say, if group LIKE 'KT%' then message.

Can LIKE be used in generic.list control?
Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. But why not do this filtering in the DB?

Comment: @wergeld, you are not missing anything.

I could do this filtering in the DB which I did but I needed an exclusion message similar to the one used with the generic.list control.

That's why I was hoping that the problem could be resolved using stored procedure. This way, I could say something like, If user's group is not in the list below, then give message that this user is not eligible to participate.

IvanH, I am a bit confused with your proposed solution. I think it is a good solution but I just don't understand it.

Comment: Okay, how about you do the filtering in the DB but instead of removing the records you just flag them as excluded if they match the criteria? Not sure what the "exclusion message" is so I am probably off base.

Comment: @wergeld, the exclusionary message is in the IF statement I posted at top. Please see it again below:

`If Not listOfGroups .Contains(txtPre.Text) Then
            lblNA.Text = "Members in group<b>" & txtPre.Text & "</b> are not eligible to participate in this event."
        End If`
`txtPre.Text` represents any group in the list. So, if they select a user and that user belongs to any of the groups (txtPre.Text), then give the message that user is not eligible to participate.

How can this replicated using stored proc?

Comment: Add a flag to the returned data called 'eligible'. Then on the front end if that flag is set to '0' grey out that selection from the list with some kind of footer or note stating why this user is greyed out.

Comment: If you have an algorithm which can filter records using data stored on server with a limited number of parameters it is to write a query/stored procedure. If there is a large uncompressible set of data on client it is necessary to accomplish a large data transfer before filtering.

Comment: Could a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) be of use to you? [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008 Using Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) has lots of information.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I my issue though is that I have the following that I want to exclude from participating:
`'ML', 'PA', 'MP', 'CH', 'SC', 'CP'`. In other words, any user who belongs to any of these groups is not allowed to participate.

The problem, as stated at beginning is that there are over two hundred thousand of these records and I have to use the LIKE statement to get all of them.

How can this be used with the TVP that you alluded to?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the list-of-groups you show intended to exclude *all* groups which start with a particular two-letter pair? If that is the case, then perhaps you could split the database column for the group name into two columns: the initial two letters and the rest of it. That way, you would be down to (a maximum of) 676 two-letter pairs to filter on and avoid the `LIKE` part of the query.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, still not sure how to approach your suggestes solution, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I try to formulate the problem my way:
You have a query like

```
select * form TableName where Field in ('ML02A', 'ML02B', 'ML03', ...)
```

from an unspecified reason the set of values is in program no in the database and list is very long and it cause the query being slow.

For similar situation I am using temporary table and [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). (The code should be after numbered list but formatting would not be correct).

```
Dim BulkData As SqlBulkCopy
BulkData = New SqlBulkCopy(cn)
BulkData.DestinationTableName = mDBTableName
BulkData.WriteToServer(mTableToTransfer)
```

1. Create a table for data `mDBTableName` (for utilization of server cache permanent
   one is better than temporary -#)
2. Create a `DataTable` with the same structure
3. Put data from the `list` to `DataTable` `mTableToTransfer`
4. Transfer to server
5. Run the query with join to the table

If the table structures does not match it is possible to use `BulkData.ColumnMappings.Add`